# No more than 9 arguments in QString arg? How to deal with it?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I write a long QString with more than 9 arguments, I simply use it like this:

```
QString html = QObject::tr(
                "%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 ...").arg(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);
```

But QtCreator yields and error, that there can not be more than 9 args ... I read the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html, where there is an `arg` function definition:

`QString    arg(const QString & a1, const QString & a2, const QString & a3, const QString & a4, const QString & a5, const QString & a6, const QString & a7, const QString & a8, const QString & a9) const`

So it seems that's the issue. Is there any elegant way I can deal with this, or I can only concatenate  2 strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can chain `.arg()` calls like this, with up to 9 arguments in each one:

```
QObject::tr("%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 ...")
    .arg(a, b, c)
    .arg(d)
    .arg(e, f, g, h)
    .arg(i, j);
```

Comment: What if I don't know, how many arguments I will have? Because, for instance, arguments are given by the user and there is no limit for arguments?

Comment: You could set up a `QString temp(QObject::tr(...));` and call `.arg` with one argument on it in a loop.

Comment: @yak How do you know the pattern then? Are you maybe just trying to concatenate strings? If so, just call [`.append`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#append) in a loop, or [QStringList.join](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#join) if they are stored in [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html)

Comment: It might be a good idea to add something like `.args({initializer list here})`